# Question about Rashi being taught by angels

Tags: torah-study, rashi

Is there a Torah source (or sources) claiming Rashi was taught his Torah commentary by malachim? I remember hearing this many years ago from one of my uncles, but I haven't been able to find any sources substantiating it.

Comment: It's not in the Shem HaGedolim.

Comment: Is that a sefer?

Comment: It's the most authoritative work on who wrote what, written by Chida.

Comment: I can't find anything either. Maybe it is a metaphore for Rabbi Isaac ben Eliezer Halevi teaching Rashi Torah and being compared to "a messenger of the L-rd of Hosts" (Malachi 2:7 and Chagigah 15b)?